# Strongly Typed View Not Found When Loading From External Library

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**Background**

I have an MVC 4 application that I am trying to fit into a pluggable architecture. I am loading dlls within the Areas directory that are named "VS.Web.IPortal.Apps.*.dll".

**Problem**

This is all working, except when using strongly-typed views. Are there any troubleshooting or debugging methods that can help understand what is being done to "find" the view that the MVC Routing engine is looking for?

ERROR AT THE BOTTOM

**Code**

Here's the code that is relevant to what I'm doing.

*PluggableInterface.dll*

A standard class library, with one class ApplicationDynamicDiscovery.

Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(ApplicationDynamicDiscovery), "Discover")]
```

ApplicationDynamicDiscovery.cs

```
public static class ApplicationDynamicDiscovery
{        
    /// <summary>
    /// Discover all dlls that meet the spec in the path. This is static, so that it happens
    /// before startup - this works.
    /// </summary>
    public static void Discover()
    {
        var areasDir = new DirectoryInfo(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Areas"));

        if (!areasDir.Exists)
        {
            return;
        }

        var assemblies = areasDir.GetDirectories()
                .SelectMany(d => d.GetDirectories("bin", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
                .SelectMany(d => d.GetFiles("VS.Web.IPortal.Apps.*.dll", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly))
                .Select(f => Assembly.LoadFile(f.FullName));

        // register all the assemblies.
        assemblies.ToList().ForEach(BuildManager.AddReferencedAssembly);
    }
}
```

*MainMvcApp* 
The main application doesn't have any custom code - it was created using the MVC 4 Internet Application Template. 
Create a project Reference to PluggableInterface.dll.

*MvcApp*
Create this project inside of the Areas folder of MainMvcApp.

MvcAppAreaRegistration.cs

```
namespace VS.Web.IPortal.Apps.MvcApp
{
    public class MvcAppAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration
    {
        public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "MvcApp";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            // Default route
            context.MapRoute(
                    "MvcApp_default",
                    "MvcApp/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                    new string[] { "VS.Web.IPortal.Apps.MvcApp.Controllers" }
                );
        }
    }
}
```

Controllers/MvcAppController.cs

```
namespace VS.Web.IPortal.Apps.MvcApp.Controllers
{
    public class MvcAppController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return this.View(new MvcAppModel { Name = "Test" });
        }
    }
}
```

Models/MvcAppModel.cs

```
namespace VS.Web.IPortal.Apps.MvcApp.Models
{
    public class MvcAppModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Views/MvcApp/Index.cshtml

```
@model VS.Web.IPortal.Apps.MvcApp.Models.MvcAppModel

<h2>title - @Model.Name </h2>
```

With that in place - I can start the server and I browse to localhost:port/MvcApp/MvcApp I receive the following error

```
The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Areas/MvcApp/Views/MvcApp/Index.aspx
~/Areas/MvcApp/Views/MvcApp/Index.ascx
~/Areas/MvcApp/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Areas/MvcApp/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/MvcApp/Index.aspx
~/Views/MvcApp/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Areas/MvcApp/Views/MvcApp/Index.cshtml
~/Areas/MvcApp/Views/MvcApp/Index.vbhtml
~/Areas/MvcApp/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Areas/MvcApp/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/MvcApp/Index.cshtml
~/Views/MvcApp/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml
```

If I remove the `@model VS.Web.IPortal.Apps.MvcApp.Models.MvcAppModel` from the view it works. 
If I remove the reference to the PluggableInterface project and add the MvcApp project it works with the strongly typed model. 
Anyone that can point me to how to troubleshoot this routing issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by keeping track of the assemblies after I've added them, and then adding an assembly resolver. I don't know if it's the best solution, but it seems to do the trick.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomainAssemblyResolve;
ApplicationDynamicDiscovery.Assemblies = new List<Assembly>();
```

CurrentDomainAssemblyResolve function:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Look through the dynamically loaded assemblies, when looking for an assembly.
    /// </summary>
    private static Assembly CurrentDomainAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.RequestingAssembly != null)
        {
            return args.RequestingAssembly;
        }

        // might return null
        return ApplicationDynamicDiscovery.Assemblies.SingleOrDefault(x => x.FullName == args.Name);
    }
```